# VSX: Save ProjectItem in folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I have an visual studio 2015 extension which reads files from a DB and creates a solution and project from a template. The files are then added as ProjectItems to the project (type VSProject2).

I would like to save the files in a folder, together with the csproj and sln file so that one can open it later without the extension.

However, the folder which contains the files in the solution window, is empty on disk.

So I'm confused. I've tried to save the projectItems, but it still doesn't end up in die folder on disk.

I add the folder with variable name "foldername" to the project. Let's make it TimeAndAttendance. So on disk a folder TempProject is created and in that, a folder TimeAndAttendance. I would like the csproj file and the source files (added as ProjectItems) to be saved in that folder.

```
  public void CreateSolution()
    {
        // This function creates a solution and adds a Visual C# Class library project to it.
        try
        {
            Solution2 soln = (Solution2)visualStudioInstance.Solution;
            String csTemplatePath;
            Project projCS = null;
            parameterWindowEventsList = new Dictionary<EnvDTE.Window, WindowEvents>();

            String csPrjPath = Path.Combine(Config.Cluster.WorkingPath, "TempProject");

            if (Directory.Exists(csPrjPath))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(csPrjPath);
                foreach (var dir in di.GetDirectories())
                {
                    dir.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dir.FullName);
                    fi.IsReadOnly = false;
                    dir.Delete(true);
                }
                di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                di.Delete(true);
            }

            csTemplatePath = soln.GetProjectTemplate("TAEngineTemplate.zip", "CSharp");
            // Create a new C# Class Library project using the template obtained above.
            soln.AddFromTemplate(csTemplatePath, csPrjPath, "TAEngineProject", false);

            foreach (Project p in soln.Projects)
            {
                if (String.Compare(p.Name, "TAEngineProject") == 0)
                {
                    projCS = p;
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

            if (projCS != null)
            {
                taEngineProject = projCS.Object as VSProject2;
            }

            taEngineProject.References.Add(Path.Combine(Config.Engine.EngineBinPath, "Engines.TimeAndAttendance.dll"));

            taEngineProject.References.Add("System.Data.DLL");
            taEngineProject.References.Add("System.Xml.DLL");
            taEngineProject.References.Add("System.Core.dll");

            taEngineProject.Project.ProjectItems.AddFolder(folderName);
            taEngineProject.Project.Save(null);                      

        }
        catch (SystemException ex)
        {
            log.Error("Problem with creating solution. " + ex);
        }
    }
```

The last line 
 `taEngineProject.Project.Save(null);`
doesn't seem to do anything.

The following is where I load a source file as a ProjectItem. Any improvement on how to do it without the try-catch functionality is also welcome. I inherited this code and just shook my head the first time I saw it, but I don't know how to improve it either. :-(

```
public ProjectItem LoadAsProjectItem(string sourcePath)
    {
        if (taEngineProject != null)
        {
            string filename = sourcePath.Substring(sourcePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            ProjectItem retItem;
            ProjectItem projFolderItem = taEngineProject.Project.ProjectItems.Item(folderName);
            try
            {
                retItem = projFolderItem.ProjectItems.Item(filename);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                retItem = projFolderItem.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(sourcePath);

            }

            return retItem;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Does it throw any exception? is the folder named csPrjPath (the value of variable named csPrjPath) created?

Comment: csPrjPath is created (in the C drive), and it is the folder called TempProject, and the csproj file is created in that. In TempProject is the folder "Time and Attendance". 
But now, this folder is also in my solution explorer. In the solution explorer, the source files are added to the Time and Attendance folder in the project, but when I look at the TempProject folder in the C drive, the "Time and Attendance" folder is empty. 
If I try to save the csproj file in the "Time and Attendance" folder in the C drive, it throws an excpetion saying that it is only allowed in the TempProject folder.

Comment: Based on your description, I create a simple, the project file will copy to the folder csPrjPath, if you want to copy file to  the folder named 'Time and Attendance', you can change the value of variable named csPrjPath with "'Time and Attendance'"

Comment: Yeah I guess so...

Comment: I would just like to know why I can't save the source files in the folder on disk.

Comment: Based on your code snippet, you only add a folder in your project, i could find any code to add related source files in the folder, just add some references.

Comment: In the last method LoadAsProjectItem, the source files are added to the project.  
retItem = projFolderItem.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(sourcePath);
Not sure whether that was what you were looking for?